# Who should be credited for the definition of rank in the von Neumann universe

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

In the von Neumann universe (also known as the cumulative hierarchy), the rank $R(x)$ is defined as the least ordinal $\alpha$ that $x\in V_{\alpha +1}$ (or equivalently $x\subset V_{\alpha}$). I'd like to know who gave this definition and when.

Comment: You asked and deleted this question a while ago.

Comment: The question has been changed (completely).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The modern definition of rank appears to have arisen gradually. The introduction of [Christine Knoche's $1973$ masters thesis](https://preserve.lehigh.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5189&context=etd) gives a good summary: it seems to have begun with Mirimanoff in $1917$ and been given its modern form by Tarski in $1955$. Along the way von Neumann, Russell, and Bernays (and others) played with it in various ways.

I think it would ultimately be an oversimplification to try to credit it to any individual author - nor is there any particular need to.

Comment: I do not think it should be credited to Mirimanoff because he only raised a vague idea of rank in his seminal paper "Les antinomies de Russell et de Burali-Forti et le probleme fondamental de la theorie des ensembles" in 1917, while the von Neumann universe came after 1930 (in Zermelo's paper).

Comment: @ Noah Schweber, thanks a lot. Yes, knoche's thesis provides a good summary on rank function upon which a lot of research has been done already.